# Conditional stylesheet in Nuxt

Tags: css, vue.js, internet-explorer, stylesheet, nuxt.js

My CSS is not rendering well in Internet explorer even after using IE prefixes. So I want to try conditional stylesheet, but I'm not sure how to go about that in Nuxt

In Nuxt the best bet is to use CSS Conditional stylesheet in `nuxt.config.js` or use it in the `default.vue` template, but that does not fit in there since conditional stylesheet is normally applied in the head tag.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This a typical example of what I want to try. If I can get help on how to format it so it can be used in the `nuxt.config.js` or in Vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the default HTML template from Nuxt.

Create a new file "app.html" at the root of your project and set your custom html template with .

see doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#document

```
// app.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css"><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```